# Выполнение цикла while с запросом пароля

Tags: c#, winforms, while

пытаюсь выполнить цикл while но с условием чтобы после 3 неправильного ввода пароля, то есть после 3 попыток входа на аккаунт у нас должен выводится что ваш аккаунт заблокирован и пользователь больше не мог ничего писать в textbox. Пытался выполнить с циклом for, do...while. Но у меня задание именно на while. Не могу понять как сделать. Вот код формы

```
namespace WinFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int i = 1;
        private void btnBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string log = txtLog.Text;
            string pas = txtPas.Text;

            while (i <= 3)
            {
                if (log == "Dimas" && pas == "12345")
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblRes.Text = "Допуск разрешён";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblRes.Text = "Допуск запрещён";
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здесь не нужен цикл, просто в обработчике кнопки, если неправильно введены данные, прибавляй к i единицу, и проверяй, что если `i == 3`, то выводи msgBox с ошибкой

Comment: ну и `i` очевидно должно быть равно нулю (`i=0`) изначально

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать небольшой код?

Comment: И мне сказали что только с помощью while и чтобы вывести это сообщение "Аккаунт заблокирован" это надо как-то в цикл добавить чтобы после 3 раз цикл выводил сообщение

Comment: вы уверены что задачу необходимо выполнить через форму а не с помощью консоли?

Comment: Да, мне препод сказал что это просто решить но я не нашёл пока как это сделать

Comment: в общем нет смысла делать while внутри процедуры btnBut_click() т.к. для проверки необходимо нажимать на кнопку и при нажатии кнопки, while будет отрабатывать три раза( по сути то же самое что и цикл for), плюс счетчик должен прибавлять 1 после каждой неудачной попытки а не просто в конце цикла. добавь текст самой задачки, а то совсем не понятно выходит

Comment: Сделать аутентификацию (попытки) на 3 раза, если пользователь 3 раза ввёл неправильно логин и пароль то на 4 раз написать что ваша карточка заблокирована, с помощью цикла while

Answer (score 0):

Все проще, чем кажется:

```
namespace WinFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int i = 0;
        private void btnBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtLog.Text == "Dimas" && txtPas.Text == "12345")
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    lblRes.Text = "Допуск разрешён";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
                    lblRes.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblRes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblRes.Text = "Допуск запрещён";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, но мне нужно именно с циклом while можете подсказать как сделать?

Comment: @Димас если я верно понял вашу задумку: вы хотите чтобы форма на лету проверяла данные без нажатия кнопки. Проверки должны повторяться до тех пор, пока количество успешных вводов не будет равно трем?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы у пользователя при нажатии на кнопку проверялся логин и пароль но если логин или пароль не совпадут 3 раза то выходила ошибка что "Ваш аккаунт заблокирован!""